# I want to work with two button in Android Studio

Tags: android, button, android-studio

I am beginner in Android Studio. I want to use 2 button but it always ı a getting an error. I am working another Computer,so ı can not send you a code view. 
Can you help me,if you  have a example code about this subject?

Comment: yes .You can explain more

Comment: Which error you got?

Comment: you need to give more explanation on what you want to do exactly

Comment: try to follow some tutorial for very beginners. you can find some on YouTube or some site like http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Android/article.html

Comment: Attend [How to develop android apps](https://www.udacity.com/course/developing-android-apps--ud853) course prepared by Google officially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is straight from android documentation. the link is here: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

```
     public class MyActivity extends Activity {
     protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
     super.onCreate(icicle);

     setContentView(R.layout.content_layout_id);

     final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // Perform action on click
         }
     });
   }
 }
```

so you retrieve a button from xml with "findViewById" method. or you can      programmatically add the view by initializing the button like this

```
Button bt = new Button(this); //"this" if inside a view or activity class or        you have to get context somehow
ViewGroup.LayoutParams vl = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(height, width);
bt.setLayoutParams(vl);

ViewGroup vg = new ViewGroup(this);
vg.addView(bt);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is simple way of use button.

**In layout file**

```
 <Button
       android:id="@+id/button1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Button 1"/>

<Button
       android:id="@+id/button2"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Button 2"/>
```

**Define buttons**

```
Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
```

**Click event for button**

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});

btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: This is what I would have posted. +1

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

**STEP ONE - Create a XML layout with the two buttons**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="net.napples.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BUTTON 1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BUTTON 2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**STEP TWO - Create a java class for the activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /* UI Views */
    Button mButton1;
    Button mButton2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Get UI references
        findViewsById();

        // Set listener for the Views (like ImageView, TextView, Button, etc)
        setListenerForViews();
    }

    private void findViewsById() {

        try {
            /* Get a reference for each button */
            mButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            mButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        } catch (NullPointerException exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void setListenerForViews() {

        mButton1.setOnClickListener(myListener);
        mButton2.setOnClickListener(myListener);

    }

    View.OnClickListener myListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // See Step 3
        }
    };
}
```

**STEP THREE - Create a listener to manage the click on each button**

```
View.OnClickListener myListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view == mButton1)
            /* Your code, for example start a new Activity */
            startActivity(this, SecondActivity.class);
        if (view == mButton2) 
            /* Your code, for example set text for a TextView */
            mTextView1.setText("New text");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all your answers. I was trying to solve the problem that using two button to write text. But i solved like this;

```
    final TextView text= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    final TextView text2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text2);
    Button buton2= (Button)findViewById(R.id.buton2);
    Button buton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buton);
    buton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            text.setText("Hi!");
        }
    });

    buton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            text2.setText("Whats's up?");
        }
    });
```